# Upscale layer with deconvolution or other

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I need to use an upscale layer in caffe which "doubles" the pixels. A 10x10 image becomes 20x20 with pixels "doubled" in both horizontal and vertical dimension. I heard that deconv layer may help with a stride of 2, no padding and a kernel size of 1x1 but this put zeros between pixels. Does anyone can help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try kernel size of 2 and weights init (and fixed?) to 1.

```
layer {
  name: "upsample"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: x
  top: y
  convolution_param {
    num_output:  # same as number of input channels
    group:       # same as number of channels 
    bias_term: false # no need for bias
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    pad: 0
    weight_filler: { type: "constant" val: 1 }
  }
  param { lr_mult: 0 }
}
```

Note the `group` and `num_output` should be equal so you have the same kernel acting on each channel independently.